# How to get the number of clicks previous to a click?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table `events` on a PostgreSQL 9.5.2 database with the columns `id`, `userid` and `event_datetime`. I want to count for every event the number of previous events in a user's session (the last thirty minutes). This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT T1.id, COUNT(*) "cnt"
FROM events T1 
INNER JOIN events T2 
    ON T1.userid = T2.userid
   AND T1.event_datetime > T2.event_datetime -- T1 happened later than T2
   AND T1.event_datetime - INTERVAL '30 MINUTES' < T2.event_datetime  -- but not more than 30 minutes
GROUP BY T1.id;
```

However, the `events` table is very large, and the query above takes ages. Do you see a way how I could optimize this?

**edit:** I just realized that by excluding the *anonymous user* I could drastically reduce the table size. That solved my problem for the moment. Still an interesting problem though. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: OT, but I'd do `GROUP BY T1.id` instead of GROUP BY 1.

Comment: Have you index on user id and event_datetime. could be that a composite index is useful

Comment: @jarlh I believe that is a good point. Can you explain why and do you have a good read/link about "The Zen of SQL"?

Comment: GROUP BY 1 is a product specific syntax. ANSI SQL doesn't allow anything but column names there.

Comment: @scaisEdge There is an index on both of them - no composite though... I will that.

Comment: I have a solution for you, but before we bring the heavy guns, let check something. Could you check the execution plan and tell me what is the current join algorithm (nested loops / hash / merge) ? Also could you estimate what is the maximum number of events per user?

Comment: Do you need exact results where interval's duration is exactly 1800 seconds, or it is acceptable to have some approximations? You can pre-calculate summary for each, say, 5-minute interval and then calculate the rolling sum of these 5-minute intervals more efficiently than the self-join that you have now.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz In order to answer your question I counted the events per user and realized that the unknown user has about 150k events, where the others had only about 100. So by excluding that user the query runs in less then a minute and not hours.

Comment: This is a good start. Can you tell me about the execution plan (with that user)?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yeah that would be totally fine. I thought of splitting the table in hour batches in order to self join only on smaller tables, but no clue if that is a good way to do it.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I actually never worked with execution plans before. I ran a `explain (verbose true, analyze true) SELECT ...`, that has a ` hash aggregate(nested loop(Seq scan, index scan))` But one minute execution time is totally fine. It's used for analysis not in live systems.

Comment: @asPlankBridge, your question looks similar to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/date-range-rolling-sum-using-window-functions That question on dba.se is for SQL Server, but Postgres has the same set of features, so the queries can be converted to Postgres syntax. That question is for daily data, in your case you'd have different granularity (say, 5 minutes), but the overall idea would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Biased user with 150**K** events causing the performence issues.
Remove this user from the query.

---

Later on I'll send a solution that doesn't involve removing users.